# How to repeatedly paint image?

Tags: java

I am trying to make simple car game from Java Swing. I want the background to move. When the background image moves down, I have to again paint it continuously.
How can I do that?
P.S: background and background1 are the same image

```
package com.mycompany.cardemo.car;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
*
* @author Suraj Gautam
*/
public class MainScreen extends JPanel implements ActionListener {



  Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
  private ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/background.png"));
  private ImageIcon background2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/background1.png"));
  private int x = 0;
  private int y = 0;
  private int velX = 1;
  private int velY = 1;

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    background.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    if (y > 0 && y<400) {
        background2.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    }


    timer.start();

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Car game");
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new MainScreen());
    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setVisible(true);

  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    y += velY;
    repaint();

  }

  public void updateValueOfy(int y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

background2.paintIcon is not working here

Comment: I tried your program, background2.paintIcon works for me. One thing to note is that your frame size is 400 by 400, and your condition to paint background2 is when y > 0 and y < 400. So throughout the visual area of your frame, background2 will always be painted. What are trying to achieve here by having background1 and background2 here exactly?

Comment: I don't want that frame to be empty. I want the images to move repeatedly. Whenever the background image moves, immediately I want next image to be painted so that the frame won't seem blank.

Answer (score 1):

In your program  `background.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);` and  `background2.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);` will paint image2 on top of image1 since they have the same origin point (x,y).

What you need to do at least is `background2.paintIcon(this, g, x, y + background.getIconHeight());` so that image1 and image 2 does not overlap.

Furthermore, to achieve your end goal, you need to use Y as an anchor point for your painting, to paint the 2 images repeatedly over the entire frame, you can use the following method

1. paint image1 and image2 alternatively starting from Y downwards until the end of frame is reached
2. paint image2 and image1 alternatively starting from Y - (the height of image2) upwards until the start of the frame is reached
3. Y needs to restart from the beginning of the frame once it reached the end.
4. You need to take the heights of image1 and image2 into account when restarting Y to prevent glitch.

Below is a sample listing, which is proven to work on my computer:

```
private int bg1Height = background.getIconHeight();
private int bg2Height = background2.getIconHeight();
// painting height should be a multiple of (bg1height + bg2height) that is immediately larger than frameHeight
private int paintingHeight = ((frameHeight / (bg1Height + bg2Height)) + 1)  * (bg1Height + bg2Height);

public static int frameHeight = 400;

public MainScreen() {
    timer.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    y = (y + velY) % paintingHeight;
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // paint downwards repeatedly
    int yTemp = y;
    while (yTemp < 400) {
        background.paintIcon(this, g, x, yTemp);
        yTemp += bg1Height;
        if (yTemp < 400) {
            background2.paintIcon(this, g, x, yTemp);
            yTemp += bg2Height;
        }
    }

    // paint upwards repeatedly
    yTemp = y;
    while (yTemp > 0) {
        yTemp -= bg2Height;
        background2.paintIcon(this, g, x, yTemp);
        if (yTemp > 0) {
            yTemp -= bg1Height;
            background.paintIcon(this, g, x, yTemp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image doesn't move at all?

Comment: I moved the timer.start() to the MainScreen's constructor because timer only needs to be started once. Maybe you missed that part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want paint image repeatedly again from location `(0,0)` just reset your `x and y` coordinate as below: 
Assume your maximum height of `JFrame` is 400.

```
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(y >= 400) {
        y = 0;  x = 0;
    }

    background.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    timer.start();

  }
```